# Are there way to overcome field max length barrier in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have this xml:

```
    <field name="text" type="text_en" default="" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
  <field name="text" type="keyword_content" default="" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <fieldType name="keyword_content" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer name="keyword"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer name="keyword"/>
      </analyzer>    
   </fieldType>

   <copyField source="text" dest="text_exact" />
```

And on reindex i'm getting error with large documents. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Are you referring to the "max token length of 32178 bytes exceeded" error? In that case, don't use a keyword tokenizer for your field - but use a regular tokenizer Having an exact match for a whole file isn't really suitable for Solr.

Comment: Ok how can i add exact match then?

Comment: You can add a hash of the file instead of the actual content - depending on the hash algorithm these are 32-50 bytes. If you need to retrieve a file from its content that would be far more effective (not sure how you'd send the extracted text to query for the file in the first place if you didn't already know what the extracted content was). Do you have an example of your exact use case? An exact match would mean that what you're using in the query is the _exact same text, whitespace, casing, newlines, and all_, as what Tika extracted).

Comment: If you want to keep the _words_ exact, use a whitespace tokenizer without any stemming/etc. - that way you can match the terms in the document exactly, without having to match the whole document.

Comment: then i can just add:
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer name="whitespace"/>
      </analyzer> ? And will it work for field with big text value?

Comment: no, not if you only do it for queries - the error is an indexing error usually. But whether it behaves as you want depends on _how you want it to behave_ (which is why I asked about what you're actually trying to do). You will also want to have a lowercase filter if you want your matches to be case insensitive.

Comment: I have a text field with big text value and i need to get document which this value contains specific word or phrase. Currently if i write some word it returning documents which may contain similar word but i need exact result

Comment: Thank you for your help. Looks like i solved this issue

Comment: Great, then you're not looking for exact search - that means that a field would match exactly with its complete value (not parts of the field). A whitespace tokenizer without further processing is probably sufficient in that case.